# Inserting Laravel translation variables in to email inline styles

Tags: php, laravel

We have been white-labelling our soloution using Laravel's translate functions.
We have now got to the stage where we are working on email templates.

**The question is: Is there any way we can insert these translation variables into inline css?**

We have already managed to white-label the website CSS, but obviously, the email styling would need to be treated differently as it is all inline.

Here, for example, is the footer of the emails:

```
<tr style="background: #333333;">
    <td style="padding: 30px 120px;">
        <p class="white" style="color: #fff; line-height: 32px;">
             {{ trans('region.name.name', [], $locale) }}©&nbsp; {{ date("Y") }}
             <br />
             {{ trans('region.emails.support.email', [], $locale) }} | {{ trans('region.phoneFriendly', [], $locale) }}<br>
        </p>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

You can see:

```
{{ trans('region.name.name', [], $locale) }}
```

and

```
{{ trans('region.emails.support.email', [], $locale) }}
```

and

```
{{ trans('region.phoneFriendly', [], $locale) }}
```

Populate the footer with contact details.

What I am wondering is, is there a way to insert hex codes into the style elements, like this:

```
<p class="white" style="color: {{ trans('region.emails.support.email', [], $locale) }}; line-height: 32px;">
```

Obviously, that doesn't work but should illustrate what we are trying to achieve.

Insights massively appreciated. Asking on behalf of my developers to see if I can save them some time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by using an escaped function like

```
{!! trans('nav.find') !!}
```

so in your case, it would be

```
<p class="white" style="color: {!! trans('region.emails.support.email', [], $locale) !!}; line-height: 32px;">
```

BTW don't you think that the value should come from the database instead of from the locale's file.